# How to render template after getting all the required data from service angular2?

Tags: angular

I am facing an issue that data is not populating in combo boxes in page load.

My query is that how to render template after getting necessary data in component in angular 2 ?

Comment: What's the problem? How does the code look like? Code would make it much easier to understand what your problem is and how a solution could look like.

Comment: i have implemented custom reusable drop down component and used that component in one of form.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can reload/rerender template on any event just follow this code

```
AppComponent.reload.detectChanges();
```